# Regarding various way of calling a method

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, backgroundworker, threadpool

very rare i worked with thread, background worker etc but never try to know when which one we should use and how each technique works internally. so here i am asking few question regarding thread,asynchronously calling method, background worker or TPL. i apologized here i have asked few question.  my request is please read it and answer in details.

1. when we run our apps then apps start with a thread which is called main thread. GUI related controls are created on another thread how far i heard....is it true ? is there any thread created for GUI ?
2. when we call few method then all method calls happen sequentially means one method calls stand & end then next method will star and everything happens in main thread. that is why main thread gets blocked. if we do not want to block main thread then we always like to run methods on another thread means asynchronously. is it true that asynchronously invoking any method means executing method on separate thread? if not does it mean asynchronously invoking any method which execute in same thread without blocking main thread? if yes then how it is possible.please explain in details.
3. what is actually happen when we call any method asynchronously which does not block main thread? i need to know what is going on behind the curtain.
4. what is the difference between calling method through thread.start and calling method asynchronously ?
5. background worker execute method asynchronously in same main thread or in separate thread?
6. when we invoke a method with thread.start then how can i specify callback that when my method finish then a callback will occur and let me know that method finish. i try to find such example with thread.start but found none. so help me to do it with sample code.
7. what is the main objective of task parallel library. TPL does execute any method in main thread or in separate thread?

we can use thread.start or background worker or calling any method asynchronously to solve our purpose then what extra things is giving TPL for which people use it?

Comment: I was going to answer but I found myself repeating myself. Do some research the BackgroundWork class and come back and revise your question to one question. Every single question can be answered by yourself if you research what the difference between asynchronous and synchronous threads are.  I am flagging this has not being constructive since you have 7 different questions and most of them are very broad.

Comment: You should be asking one question per question, not 7 questions in one.  As Ramhound has said, a few of these questions are either the same, or could be combined into one question, but several of them are different and should be in their own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You GUI thread is the same thread as the threat that your application starts with. By default your application is just a single thread (okay... on the background are multiple threads, but those handle some .NET-stuff like garbage collection, you do not need to worry about that).

Besides the main threads there are multiple threading mechanisms. All use essentially the same thing: the Thread class. So yes, all other threaded operations do not run on the main thread.

Every threading mechanisme has pro's and con's:

**Thread class**
The thread class is the base of them all. You can Start it, Join in (wait till it is finished) and Abort it (`Abort` is deprecated and useing it is not recommended). Creating a new thread take relativly a lot of time (on my machine +/- 5 ms). It does not provide for any other synchronization mechanismes as callbacks. You have to write them yourself.

**ThreadPool**
Because the threads are created very slowly, .NET has a threadpool. The threadpool standy ready for async-operations. When a async-operation is queued, the threadpool picks it up and assigns it to a already created and idle thread. The thread will execute that operation. You can queue a operation with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. A callback is possible. The TreadPool should only be used for fast operations. I/O operations can take up a lot of time, which might block other queued operations.

**ASync calls**
.NET has a lot of different async calls, like with delegates `InvokeAsync`. Most of these operations are pushed into the queue of the ThreadPool and because of that all these methods support it too. So very handy. Most I/O operations like (StreamReader.BeginRead) are execute on a newly created thread.

**BackgroundWorker**
The BackgroundWorker also uses the ThreadPool to process al of its operations.

**Parallel**
The Parallel-class came with .NET framework 4.0. It has been create to make operations on (large) collections easier. All the operations which need to be done on all the items inside the collection are divided into several threads (on the TreadPool) allowing the workload to be divided over all the cores of a multicore processor.

Comment: *"All these operations are pushed into the queue of the ThreadPool"* -- not the case with all I/O methods, actually.  When possible, I/O async calls will use the I/O completion port facility, which means that they will not consume a thread at all.

Comment: Also, it is worth noting that `Thread.Abort()` is deprecated, and should not be used.  When a thread is aborted, `finally` blocks in the call stack are not run.  This has very serious consequences, such as a thread aborted while owning a monitor (e.g. in a `lock` block) will not release the monitor, leaving the object permanently locked.

Comment: @cdhowie: You are right about the I/O operations. I updated my answer. Thank you for that insite.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, using Abort has some really exiting side effects :). I have wrestled with that before. But `finally` blocks ARE called in any way (check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx). The only disadvantage is that the catch blocks with a specific exceptions are missed because the ThreadAbortException overrules other "pending" exceptions.

Comment: Ah, yes, rather the problem is if the abort operation happens between monitor acquisition and the entrance of the try block.  (`Interrupt()` doesn't have this problem since the ThreadInterruptedException is only thrown from certain points, such as blocking I/O.)